# Create a filename using the value of a Variable

Tags: python, variables, filenames

I'm trying to create a filename of a variable and it's more difficult than i realised!

I want to use the value of the `TESTNAME` variable as the name of the new file.

```
import re
with open('output.csv', 'r') as rf:
    body = rf.read()
    for line in body:
        newbody = body.rsplit("'")[0]
    print(newbody)
    SYMNAME = newbody
    with open('TEST.txt', 'w') as wf:
        wf.close
```

If i `print(TESTNAME)`, the value is `HISTORY`, but if i add it to the wf, i get this error:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'HISTORY\n'
```

I'd like the new file to be called `HISTORY.txt` via the variable..

Comment: The `\n` is a newline character that you have to string out. Do `TESTNAME = TESTNAME.strip()`. You also don't need `wf.close` - the `with` statement handles that.

Comment: There's no variable named `TESTNAME` in your code sample

Comment: The code shown here has problems, but not the ones you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is a newline in your filename. You can use `TESTNAME.strip()` as the filename instead to get rid of the trailing newline

Answer (score 0):

You can open and write to a file with

```
with open(TESTNAME+'.txt') as wf:
    wf.write("some content in your new file\n")
```

`wf.close` won't do anything, to close a file you need to call  `wf.close()`, the parenthesis here is important. Also , you don't actually need to call `wf.close()`, since using `with ...` will automatically `close()` the file.